# What are the elements of $R\, \times\, S^1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am new to using this site, and I am working on some problems from a textbook on physics that I am going through on my own. I realize that this is a very simple question, but what are the elements of the set $R\,\times\,S^1$?

I realize that $\times$ must be the Cartesian product, and I know that $S^1$ is a circle in $R^2$, from the textbook I am going through; are the elements of $R\,\times\,S^1$ pairs of points on the number line and circles centered around them? Or are they just the circles centered at each point on $R$, *without* the points on the line themselves?  Or something else?

Comment: Cylinder.......

Comment: I understand that it forms a cylinder, but what are the elements themselves, specifically? I am trying to solve a problem that states that the manifold $R\,\times\,S^1$ can be covered by a single chart, by explicitly constructing the map...

Comment: You have a cartesian product. If we have the cartesian product of two sets $A$ and $B$, what are the elements of $A\times B$?

Comment: Elements of $A\,\times\,B$ would be $(a, b), a \in A, b \in B$. So is that it? It is an ordered pair made up of points on the line and points on the circle centered around the first point?

Comment: You got it. That's really all there is. You understood that the set was the cylinder and that really was the hard part.

Comment: So, for $(a, b)$, what is $b$ in this case? I've read that $S^1$ is the locus of all points some fixed distance from the origin of $R^2$. Does that mean that $(a,b)$ is really $(a, p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots)$?

Comment: In this case, the symbol $b$ represents an element of the set $B$. For $S^1$, it depends upon how you represent the circle. How much mathematics have you had?

Comment: Please ignore the last comment I made. After thinking a little, I see what you mean by "Cylinder". Thank you, I think I can get started on solving the problem now. I've studied up to multivariable calc in college, but haven't really studied the pure aspects of math to any rigorous degree, so I'm very green when it comes to things like charts, atlases and manifolds.

Comment: To be clear, $\mathbb{R} \times S^1$ *cannot* be covered by a single chart.

Comment: Your charts are just given by produits of the charts (if you wish to know what manifold structure it has) it is the natural idea you would have if you were to picture it in your head

Comment: @CharlesHudgins There is a problem in Carroll's Introduction to GR that is asking me to do exactly that...

Comment: @Chidi you're right, I'm wrong. Observe that the punctured plane is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Map each point $(r, \theta)$ of the punctured plane to the point $(h(r), \theta)$ on the cylinder, where $h$ (for height) is your favorite diffeo from $(0, \infty)$ to $(-\infty, \infty)$

Comment: I should qualify my comment slightly. If by "chart" you mean an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you can't do it in one for topological reasons (which is what I wrongly thought of at first). The key here is that we were able to use a topologically nontrivial open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for our chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On its own, the set $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^1$ is just a set whose elements can be written as ordered pairs $(a, b)$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{S}^1$. Most of the interesting stuff happens when you bring various topological properties of those sets along for the ride - for example, we might talk about a "neighbourhood" of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ as an open interval $(a - \varepsilon, a + \varepsilon)$, and similarly for $\mathbb{S}^1$, and from those you can construct neighbourhoods of $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^1$. Note that on their own $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$ are just abstract concepts - they're sets with certain properties about how their elements are "next to" or "close to" each other in some sense.

We can also talk about "embedding" this set in another one. For example, when we "embed" $\mathbb{S}^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we take a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and create a mapping between that subset and $\mathbb{S}^1$ that keeps all the topological properties we care about. So typically the embedded set would be the unit circle $\{x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, and the mapping just takes points from $\mathbb{S}^1$ and assigns them to points on that circle in such a way that "neighbourhoods" of points from $\mathbb{S}^1$ wind up as arcs of the circle.

One way to embed $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is to notice that we can identify a bunch of subsets by fixing a value $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and looking at $S_a := \{(a, b) : b \in \mathbb{S}^1\}$. Each of these subsets is in some way "a copy of $\mathbb{S}^1$" in the sense that there's a perfect correspondence between the points of $S_a$ and the points of $\mathbb{S}^1$, so we can embed $S_a$ as the unit circle $\{(a, y, z) : y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$, and if we do that for every possible value of $a$ we get a cylinder centred around the $x$-axis (i.e. the line $y = z = 0$). However, the axis itself isn't part of the set - the point $(a, 0, 0)$ is never going to satisfy $y^2 + z^2 = 1$, just like how the origin isn't part of the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is an abstract manifold.  When you see something like that, it represents anything homeo/diffeomorphic to a line times a circle.  Any information about particular embeddings into some Euclidean space is extraneous.  Choose whatever embedding you like if you find it necessary.

Comment: I don't think @Chidi has the background to know what a manifold is. That's a guess.